# Multiselect in Angular 2

Tags: angular, select, multi-select

Here is my code: I want to use onSelect type triggering instead of change, Any help is most welcome.

```
<select multiple (change)="setSelected($event.target)">
   <option  *ngFor="let accessKey of accessKeys" [ngValue] = "accessKey">
          {{accessKey.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can simpply use primeng's Multiselect see here for more info

- https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ngModelChange**

```
 <select multiple [ngModel]="selectedOptions" (ngModelChange)="setSelected($event.target)">
    <option  *ngFor="let accessKey of accessKeys" [ngValue] = "accessKey">
       {{accessKey.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```